# c# method not returning string to python

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to call c# code from python using ctypes module. The problem is c# method returning integer value properly but not doing so for string. It returns different numbers instead of string. The number also varies each time it runs. Can anyone please tell what is the problem with this code. My python code is given below:

Python Code:

```
import ctypes
a = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r"C:\path\ConsoleApplication1.dll")
print a.mul(10,4)
print a.add(10,4)
print a.str()
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;


class Test
   {
   [DllExport("TestExport", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public static int add(int left, int right)
      {
        return left + right;
      }
   [DllExport("mul", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public static int mul(int left, int right)
      {
        return left * right;
      }
   [DllExport("str", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public static String str()
     {
       String var = "hello";
       return var;

      }

   }
```

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? I'm running into the exact same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Return Type Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810495/c-sharp-return-type-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Change following code

```
 [DllExport("str", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static String str()
 {
   String var = "hello";
   return var;

  }
```

to

```
 [DllExport("str", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static String str()
 {
   String str= "hello";
   return str;

  }
```

`var` is keyword in `c#` and cannot be used as variable name

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I changed the code as you said, still result is same.

Comment: But if i change the return type to char, it returns ascii value of the character. So  in python i can get the character using chr() function. So as string is an array of characters , how can i convert this code so that i can get the full string or array of characters in python.

Comment: C# code:                                                                                                public static char str()
    {    char  chr_value = 'a';
        return chr_value;
        }
Python: 
print chr(a.str())
Output: a

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is with the static keyword: while the method isn't exactly dynamic, assigning a value to a static method feels... off. I'm sure there are other people that can explain it in much more detail to you, but I would replace your code with one of the following:

```
public string str()
 {
   string _str = "hello";
   return _str;
  }
```

or

```
public static string str = "hello";
```

Also note as mentioned by @Rajeev you shouldn't use var as a variable name, as it is a reserved keyword. It would work as a variable name, but it's very bad practice, as it makes your code difficult to read, for example

```
var var = "hello";
return var;
```

Is valid, but super confusing. Don't do this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I can not remove static keyword, as only static method can be exported using Dllexport. And regarding your second suggestion, compiler doesn't let me do that telling invalid expression term.